# Why my var value doesn't change and is not communicated?

Tags: python, matrix, process, pipe, semaphore

I have a Python program to create two arrays, multiply them and add the result of multiplying.

This is done through processes.

If I create two processes, the program creates two arrays with two rows and two columns.
They should change the value of the var `resultado` that is global.

However the process number two receives the value of var `resultado` incorrectly as you can see in the comments in the code.

What could it be?

Some parts of program have been hidden.

```
resultado = []

def multiplicacao(pipe_filho):
    if flag:
         sem.acquire()
    global resultado
    # print resultado --> 
    #   Process 1: [] (Correct) ; 
    #   Process 2: [] (Incorrect should be [[47, 6]])
    myVar = productMatrix(A[e], B)
    resultado += myVar
    # print resultado --> 
    #   Process 1: [[47, 6]] (Correct) ;
    #   Process 2: [[36, 127]] (Correct)
    for i in range(len(myVar)):
        for j in range(len(myVar[i])):
            soma.value += myVar[i][j]
    pipe_filho.send(myVar)
    if flag:
        sem.release()

pipe_filho, pipe_pai = Pipe()

for i in range(2):
    e = i
    newP = Process(target=multiplicacao, args=(pipe_filho,))
    newP.start()

myVar = pipe_pai.recv()

for i in range(2):
    newP.join()

# printMatrix(resultado) --> 
#   | 36  95 | (Incorrect should be | 36  95  36  127 | )
```

Comment: A global variable isn't shared between processes. So I'm not sure how you expect this to work at all.

Comment: I don't have a real answer, but I see you're only joining the last `newP` process (twice). The first `for` will create one `Process`, assign it to `newP`, then it will create a second process and assign it to **the same** `newP`. Your second `for` will `join()` that "second" `newP` twice (but by then you lost the reference to your first `newP` )

Comment: Also, processes don't share memory (threads do). Maybe you wanna use threads? Or put that global `resultado` in the Pipe? (I can't fully follow the code, though... my bad **:-(** )